# How to hide specific node in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have 2 questions related to firebase realtime database.

Q1) Is it possible to hide a certain node from public and only one person have access to that node ?

( I want to save a transaction key in database and only 1-2 persons can access that key from database. )

Q2) If my security rules for database are set to public, can anyone download/access complete data or they must know the structure in order to access data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A1/** Yes it is possible to limit access to a certain node to a only subset of users. There are several approaches for that. If it is a small and more or less stable subset of users, you can check if their uid is contained in a specific node listing the admin users uids, as shown below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "secretnode": {
      //only an admin user can read
      ".read": "auth != null && root.child('adminusers/' + auth.uid).exists()"
    },
    "adminusers": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
    },
    "othernodes": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true     
    }
  }
}
```

And, for example, in the database you save the admin uids as follows:

```
DBRoot
   - adminusers
        - uid1
           - name: "aaaaaa"
           - otherDataItem: "xxxxxx"
        - uid2
           - name: "bbbbb"
           - otherDataItem: "yyyy"
```

**A2/** Yes, if your security rules for database **root** are set to public,  "anyone (can) download/access complete data". Note that, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade):

> Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child rules
>   can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already
>   declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

In other words, this means that if your security rules for the database **root** are set to public anyone can download the full JSON tree representing your data, without the need to know its structure.

Comment: Thank you! @Renaud

Comment: one more thing as mentioned above what "othernodes" in the structure represents ? for example if I'm having 8 nodes from which I have to hide 1 and rest 6 are open yo public how can i set the rules ?

Comment: You should create a rule for each node similar to the rule for this othernodes

Comment: But this could be a hectic process if I'm having many nodes. Any simplified idea that represents one for all ?

Comment: Yes, put all these nodes under a main root node.